# How can i add checkbuttons so they can print in a scale 2:1 depending on the lenght of an array containing the list of items i want to create?

Tags: python, tkinter

The task is to make an array that contains list of items which are type string and to create checkbuttons for them but they have to be in a scale 2:1.
What this means is if i have a list, example:

```
list = ["London","Paris","Lisbon","Vienna","Toronto","California","LA","NYC"]
```

For a given list table would be 4 rows(3 rows if indexing goes from 0) and 2 columns(1 column if indexing goes from 0).
I was able to make a code which only adds two columns and infinite number of rows.
My piece of code:

```
j = 0
x = 0
y = 0 
for j in range(len(Array)):
    items = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, text=Array[j], onvalue=1, offvalue=0=) 
    Array.append(items)
    items.grid(row=x, column=y, sticky=W)
    if j == len(Array)//2-1:
        x = 0
        y =y+ 1
    else:
        x =x+ 1
```

Note:
What if number of items in array is odd? What would the scale be and how would they add through checkbuttons?
Example:
7 numbers in the array, scale would be 7:?

Example of a scale 2:1, O-s will represent items:

```
O O
O O
O O 
O O
```

Comment: What are you trying to make. I believe 'proportion' is the wrong word. You could just call it table, maybe?

Comment: I meant to say scale, i gave an example below as an addon to my question.

Comment: So what is the list that is used for the example like

Comment: _"For a given list table would be 4 rows"_: There can be 4 rows as there are 4 items but how will you get 2 columns, what values are you planning on using there for column

Comment: I fixed it, now it should match the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a nested loop to make a matrix like table, like:

```
from tkinter import *

window  = Tk()
lst = ["London","Paris","Lisbon","Vienna","Toronto","California","LA","NYC"]

ROWS = 4
COLS = 2

for i in range(ROWS):
    for j in range(COLS):
        item = Checkbutton(window,text=lst[COLS*i+j],onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
        item.grid(row=i,column=j,sticky='w')
        # Can do Array.append(item) and so on here...

window.mainloop()
```

This is a very simple example to make a table like structure and also to get rid of all those other variables. Note that the number of items on the list have to be equal to `ROWS*COLS`. Here there are 8 items and 4*2 is also 8, so it is fine, else the loop will throw an indexing error at some point. Also I find this question very similar to [Creating multiple differently colored shapes using tkinter and classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67432906/13382000), which is well written to catch 'most' of those `IndexError`.

Comment: Sorry i had to delete my two previous comments, i kind of mistook something.I will draw a logic in paint and put it here so you can see.Give me a moment.Thank you for trying to help :D

Comment: Hi i realized it is quite hard to make this and i can't draw a logic.The answer you gave is acceptable so i will mark it as green because it helped.

Comment: @CupidONO Don't stop trying, you will find a way, all the best.